# Best ways of generating UML from within Emacs

Tags: org-mode

There are a bunch of [integration options between Emacs and UML tools](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/emacs.html), like [`org-mode`'s `plantuml` embedding](http://eschulte.github.io/babel-dev/DONE-integrate-plantuml-support.html), a [`plantuml` major mode](https://github.com/zwz/plantuml-mode) etc.  Of course I can try them out but I'm wondering what other people use for a UML workflow?

Embedding inside another document like `org-mode` does is a nice idea, or outputting the generated uml in another buffer live-updated would be nice too.  I'm sure people out there have some super-cute elisp functions to automate this kind of thing!

Comment: Rather late to the party, but this Q just got bumped by some answers.  Could you make the question a little more discrete and problem-oriented?  Right now, "what other people use" will solicit a lot of different, opinion-based answers, and that sort of Q&A is not well-suited to this site.

Comment: Hi @Dan, I'm not opposed to altering the question (which as you say is oldish), but people stating what they use is factual not opinion (even if their opinions were involved in deciding what to use). For example would you think it better to ask "what modules are available to generate UML and their key features"? I can't just ask "how can I generate UML from within Emacs" since as stated I already know a number of plausible answers to that question, but I want to improve on my current options.

Comment: @Dan also what are the answers that bumped this? The most recent I see is Dec '14? Or do upvotes bump threads also?

Answer (score 32):

Not sure if you want to have UML conversion from/to source code etc., but if you want to create and maintain them by hand, [`plantuml`](https://plantuml.com/) rocks!

Simple plantuml example of a sequence diagram:

```
Bob -> Alice : hello
```

[image: Rendered result of simple plantuml example]

I am successfully using `org-babel` with `plantuml` (and gnuplot and ditaa and ...) diagrams etc.  Works like a charm, once [set up](http://eschulte.github.io/babel-dev/DONE-integrate-plantuml-support.html), and html output too looks awesome when you use [any one](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes) of the `org-mode` style sheets out there.

See also Zeekat's [Making Emacs Work For Me](http://zeekat.nl/articles/making-emacs-work-for-me.html#sec-10-6) on how to setup `org-babel` and many other Emacs goodies.

Then there is graphviz's **dot**, which I am about to check out, and while not specific to UML, could also be [used in Emacs](http://www.tonyballantyne.com/graphs.html) to do UMLy diagrams.

Simple dot example:

```
graph graphname { 
                a -- b; 
                b -- c;
                b -- d;
                d -- a;
        }
```

[image: Rendered result of simple dot example]

And while we are at it, though not related to UML at all, [org-babel-gnuplot](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-gnuplot.html) shows how to use the [extremely versatile **gnuplot**](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/) in Emacs.

Answer (score 10):

I'll just toot my own horn and mention [`wsd-mode`](https://github.com/josteink/wsd-mode). It also has partial support for `org-babel`, which means you can literally embed your UML in your org-mode docs and export the result to a valid HTML-document or similar.

Compared to `plantuml-mode`, its support for syntax-highlighting and indentation is clearly and objectively superior. It also integrates nicely with `flycheck` and `company-mode`.

If you think all those "small" things matters, `wsd-mode` might be a better fit for you.

Unlike `plantuml-mode`, it doesn't depend on Java or other binaries, but instead uses a SaaS webservice to generate the diagrams.

This makes it more plug-and-play and portable and to someone this might be a better fit, but the catch is that you need to be online for it to work.

Answer (score 5):

I know graphviz has some [support for UML](http://www.ffnn.nl/pages/articles/media/uml-diagrams-using-graphviz-dot.php), and org-mode has [good support](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-dot.html) for graphviz. Perhaps the combination will work for you?

Answer (score 4):

**[WARNING]** Mouse dependency

What about `artist-mode` + `ditaa` ?

`artist-mode`- Mouse use drawer in ASCII style like simple analog [Monodraw](https://monodraw.helftone.com) for macOS. On exit we have text file in ASCII graph.

`ditaa` - can convert ur text file to image/html etc.

its useful for start using emacs for build UML. But this way use mouse so hard.
However, I'm hate mouse, like most emacs users, and I'm use [plantUML](https://github.com/skuro/plantuml-mode) in org-mode. Its keyboard friendly and epic useful tool for any uml styles.

[artis-mode](http://www.lysator.liu.se/%7Etab/artist/)

[ditaa](http://ditaa.sourceforge.net)

Comment: What about them? Please show how they relate to the question. Otherwise this risks being deleted as a "link-only answer". Thx.

Comment: @Drew I'm don't know how show it in SO format. I'm just add Example video founded in youtube.

Comment: Please try to describe what you think these things have to offer to answer the question.

Comment: @Drew please check me again.

Comment: OK, thanks for making an effort. I hope that it will be clearer to some readers.

Comment: @Bimawa, the Example usecase video is private and doesn't open.

Comment: @AmitTendulkar thanks, outdated link removed.